# difference between rootDir and baseUrl in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between rootDir and baseUrl in tyescript?

According to ts docs

Base URL

```
Base directory to resolve non-relative module names. See Module Resolution documentation for more details.
```

And rootDir

```
Specifies the root directory of input files. Only use to control the output directory structure with --outDir.
```

In my tsconfig, I added
"baseUrl": "app/javascript/src",

and haven't added anything for

```
rootDir
```

Is that correct? (this works but I am not sure if this is correct or not)

Update: rootDir gives me error since I am using absolute paths

THis is my tsconfig. (baseUrl doesn't)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "app/javascript/src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "app/javascript/.dist",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/.jsx"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

In webpack, I am resolving paths like this

```
  resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/src', 'app/javascript']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I added "baseUrl": "app/javascript/src", Is that correct?

No. If you are specifying the included files for your project (as indicated by `src`) you should be using `rootDir` (as mentioned `Specifies the root directory of input files.`).

## Reason why you are not getting an error

`baseUrl` only takes effect for non-relative imports. Your code mostly has relative imports e.g. `import something from './something'` so it's not having any adverse effect for you.